# Using a variable in html.actionlink route value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Like the title says, I am simply trying to use a variable in the route value section of an action link.  Here is my code:

```
    var viewbag = ViewBag.URL;
    @Html.ActionLink( "Back to previous page", "Index", new { viewbag = true })
```

So the second line is reading "viewbag" in as actual text instead of the variable and I cannot figure out how to make a variable instead.  So my generated url becomes "?viewbag=true" instead of what I really want.  ViewBag.URL contains a word that I set in the controller. I want that word to get passed in as a parameter to the URL so my generated URL becomes "..../?word=true"

Comment: `, new { viewbag = ViewBag.URL }` ? or even more readable`, new { url = ViewBag.URL }`(Assuming your Index action has a parameter called url)

Comment: And you didn't tell what you want!

Comment: That's because what I want is dynamic.  ViewBag.URL contains a word that I set in the controller.  I want that word to get passed in as a parameter to the URL so my generated URL becomes "..../?word=true"

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the URL set in `ViewBag.URL`, you can just go ahead and use a HTML anchor `<a>`. You've already solved the problem an action link was designed to solve. So, just do:

```
<a href="@ViewBag.URL"> Back to previous page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply making the browser go back to it's previous page?

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="history.go(-1);">Back</a>
```

That way it will truly go back to the previous page, rather than the "Index" controller specifically, regardless of what link you came from. Keep in mind though, (as Phil1970 points out) that page will be from the browser's cache rather than a one from a redirect, so any changes to content won't be reflected.

Comment: Would that get the "old" version of the page if the page is dynamic?

Comment: This is an option I might go if I can't figure the other way out.  But my page is dynamic, so it is not ideal.